# charter font with mathastext and upright txgreeks

Tags: fonts

I would like charter font with upright math, both on greek and latin symbols.  are txgreek upright and mathdesign-charter mutually incompatible?  or is mathdesign's functionality voided by upright txgreeks?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{charter} %% the main font, scaleable
%% not compatible?: \usepackage[charter]{mathdesign}
\usepackage{mathastext}
\usepackage[upright]{txgreeks}

\begin{document}

P G and L: $ P(G,L) = G\cdot\frac{1-\beta^L}{\beta^G - \beta^L} $

\end{document}
```

advice, as always, appreciated.

Comment: I do'nt understand very well why this question: you might as well write:  `\usepackage[greeklowercase=upright,charter]{mathdesign}` or `\usepackage[greeklowercase=upright]{mdbch}`.

Comment: ...which I had not known, which is why I plused the comment.

Comment: `txgreeks` loads `txfonts` which takes a number of `math group slots`. However, `txgreeks` really needs at most two fonts and with option `upright` only one. It also needs a few declarations from `txfonts`. All sum up `txgreeks` could be rewritten to load much less of `txfonts` and then your code would compile. However as pointed in the previous comment, this is really not the way to go. Besides, using `mathastext` does not (except for some special effects) make much sense when benefitting from complete text-math solutions like `mathdesign`,  `kpfonts`, etc...

Comment: the doc of `txgreeks` is clear on the fact that it is provided for people already using `txfonts`: _It is not necessary to write `\usepackage{txfonts}` prior to `\usepackage{txgreeks}`
as this is done by txgreeks itself, but for clarity of the latex source of the document
to be typeset, this is highly recommended, as txgreeks does very minor
things compared to txfonts.
Using txgreeks should be hopefully compatible with any package which is
already compatible with txfonts_ but as said in my previous comment it would be possible to rewrite `txgreeks` to take only two math groups at most

Comment: suggestion: instead of hoping l-users like me to read the doc (they are expecting orthogonality), we should add some checks and error messages to guard against obvious misuse.  bernard---can you please post your comment as an answer, for me to mark it closed and answered?

Comment: @Bernard, the previous commenter did not @-ping you. Can you write an answer for this one?

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to load all these packages: the relevant options already exist in `mathdesign`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[charter, lowercase = upright, uppercase = upright, greeklowercase = upright]{mathdesign}

\begin{document}

P G and L: $ P(G,L) = G\cdot\frac{1-\beta^L}{\beta^G - \beta^L n} $

\end{document}
```

[image]